# Unable to update child state by props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The child component is not updating the textinput values when I send them by props.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the componentDidUpdate but I can't realize what it is.

These are the step to reproduce:

1. I write manually in the inputs
2. I send values from props
3. Inputs texts are not updated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Clipboard, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class BotomQRScanner extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userField: this.props.user,
            userInitialized: this.props.userInitialized,
            passInitialized: this.props.passInitialized,
            passwordField: this.props.pass
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(previousProps) {
        if (previousProps.user !== this.props.user) {
            this.setState({ 
                userField: this.props.user, 
                passwordField: this.props.pass, 
                userInitialized: this.props.userInitialized, 
                passInitialized: this.props.passInitialized
            });
        }
    }

    handleUserChange = value => {
    this.setState({userField: value, userInitialized: true});
  }

    handlePasswordChange = value => {
    this.setState({passwordField: value, passInitialized: true});
  }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={{height: '100%', width: '100%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>

                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handleUserChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 50, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'username'}
                selectionColor={'#428AF8'}
                value={this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.userInitialized? this.state.userField : this.props.user)
            }}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => this.handlePasswordChange(value)}
                style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, height: 80, width: 200}}
                autoCapitalize = 'none'
                autoCorrect={false}
                selectTextOnFocus={true}
                placeholder={'password'}
                value={this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passwordField : this.props.pass}
              />
              <Button
              title="copy"
              onPress={() => {
              Clipboard.setString(this.state.passInitialized? this.state.passwordField : this.props.pass)
            }}
            />
          </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        width: 80,
        height: 26,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    container: {
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    right: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userField,
        userInitialized,
        passInitialized,
        passwordField,
    }
}

// where you can set your initial values from props..
componentWillMount() {
    const { user, pass, userInitialized, passInitialized } = this.props

    this.setState(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     userField: user, 
     passwordField: pass, 
     userInitialized: userInitialized, 
     passInitialized: passInitialized,
    }))
}

// where you can update props upon comparison..
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 const { user, pass, userInitialized, passInitialized } = nextProps

  if (nextProps.user !== this.props.user) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     userField: user, 
     passwordField: pass, 
     userInitialized: userInitialized, 
     passInitialized: passInitialized,
    }))  
 }
}
```

Comment: the result was the same :(

Comment: The state values have to be initialized and I also had to compare the following (nextProps.user !== this.props.user || nextProps.user !== this.state.userField)

Answer (score 1):

#### Reason

According to the official document [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

> Avoid copying props into state! This is a common mistake

```js
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 // Don't do this!
 this.state = { color: props.color };
}
```

> Only use this pattern if you intentionally want to ignore prop updates

Which is clearly not your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this before, I don't know if it will work for you, Try to check the. two data that you are comparing. Maybe the issue there is you're not passing the props or the new props isn't updated.